# Using string.Template to to replace a key withing a mappings-Dictionary with given argument

Tags: python, dictionary

My title sounds probably very unhelpful but an example should clarify.

Given this example dictionary:

```
d = { "who" : "world! My Name is $name" }
```

I want to use the `string.Template` class to substitute like this:

```
Template("Hello $who").safe_substitute(d, name = "John Doe")
```

But the `$name` key is never replaced with the given value. I guess since the key is inside the dict. I was expecting `string.Template` to first substitute everything inside `d` and then the following keys.

Is there an easy and elegant way to do this except using `string.format()` and placing `{}` for the key `who`?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use `Template` instead of `string.format()` or using the key `who`, you can use two templates.

```
Template(Template("Hello $who").safe_substitute(d)).safe_substitute(name = "John Doe")
```

Comment: I thought of this solution too but don't think it is a elegant one. I don't really need to use `format` but it would be nice if all substitutions could be done withing a single function call. Only requirement is that the formating can be done by a dictionary.

Comment: `Template("Hello " + d["who"]).safe_substitute(name = "John Doe")` then ? I don't think there is an infinite amount of ways to it but I may be wrong...